# Log in page form returning empty string to php script

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating and application with PHP and MySQL.
I have created two pages. Index.php and login.php (which holds the script for the user log in)

Every time I enter a user that is on the database to log in, it does return that there was no text entered.
I am new at this and I will really appreciate some help.
Here is my code.
Thanks in advance

**index.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pet Service Catalogue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1 style="text-align:center;"><img src="cat's paw.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="cat's  paw"/> Welcome to Pet Service Catalogue</h1>
        <p style="text-align:center;">Please enter your Log in Details:</p>

        <form style ="text-align:center;" name="LogIN" action="log_in.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p style="text-align:center;"> Email: <input type="text" name="user_email" value=""/></p>
        <p style="text-align:center;"> Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" value="" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="LogIN" />
        </form>
        <form style="text-align:center;" name="registerprovider" action="registerprovider.php">
        <p style="text-align:center;">Not Registered?:</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Register Service Provider" name="Register Service Provider"  />
        </form>
        <form style="text-align:center;" name="registerowner" action="registerowner.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Register Pet Owner" name="Registerownerbutton" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
// Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'PetServiceCatalogue') or die("Failed to connect to database:" . mysqli_error($con));


        //Get user details and put them on varaiables
         $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
         $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($POST['user_password']);

         if (!empty($user_email) && !empty($user_password))
         {
   //look up for user details on the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM owner, provider WHERE email = '$user_email' AND password = SHA('$user_password') ";
    $data = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($data);
    printf("Number of rows %d \n", $result);
    if ($result == 1) {
        //The log in has found the user
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        $user_email = $row('email');
        $user_password = $row('password');
        header("location: ownerhomepage.php");
    } else {
        //the user name or password are incorrect
        echo "Wrong user email and password";
    }
    }
    else
    {

        echo ' You must enter the user email and user password';
        ?>
    <form name="back to index" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Back to Log in page" name="Back to Log in page" /> </form>
    <?php
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Not sure but I don't think just SHA is a hash method.

Comment: Change to `$user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_email']);
$user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$POST['user_password']);` for one thing. Then fix your `SHA` method, while making sure the storage method matches.

Comment: Do the above then change `AND password = SHA('$user_password')` to just `AND password = '$user_password'` and create an entry in your DB with just `username` and `password` as a test, be sure to set your column to `VARCHAR(255)` too. Then try that login again, and you'll see it's going to work. If you haven't already, you need a hashing method that will create the hash, then the insert into DB. Take my word for it, I wouldn't lie to you. Have I ever lied to you before? ;-)

Comment: I have made the changes, but Still the sql query finds nothing on the database. The connection to the database does not give any errors therefore I don't know why the query returns no result

Comment: You can't use just `SHA`; there are multiple methods such as `SHA-1` `SHA-256` and `SHA-512` etc. Plus, you would need to have created a password using the same hash method in order to retrieve it from the database. See this page in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

Comment: Plus, what version of PHP is it that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You have the action: `action="log_in.php"`but you've written its name is `login.php`

**EDIT**

Maybe you should try this as the first if statement:

```
if (trim($user_email)!="" && $user_password!=""){
//YOUR CODE
}
```

Comment: I had a look into that, but it is well written in the code. I just didn't write the pages names well on the explanation. Thanks anyway. Still not working. I am desperate.